# How to write theoretical answers? If it is referring to official documentation

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderation, moderators, moderator-intervention

Update:

Answer is deleted again now after 2 weeks after restoring. I had made changes to the answer with bullet point answer about every storage engine.

What contents are plagiarized? How can I write answer which is theoretical and have references from official doc. How do you define documentation plagiarism?

Answer is not changed a bit in 2 weeks. Then how it is deleted again? Is there any coordination between moderators? How do moderators defend decisions of answer deleting or undelete? Can I get feedback so improvements (do's and dont's) can be done for future for theoretical/ documentation answers?

---

How do I write purely theoretical answers if a question has references in official documentation? Why can't we use technical terms from the official documentation?

I had faced issue from Moderators.

Question was about different MySQL engines?

[What are MySQL database engines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35744709/1045444)

I had written an answer back 2.5 yrs ago. I had used mainly technical terms from doc of MySQL. You can say main sentences were used as part of answer to understand each storage engine view.

We had policy to not use links directly and have some easy explanation of doc.

Also I had answered it almost after 6 years of first answer and it is liked by many to understand concepts. (I am saying based on votes it got)?

Pardon me if I am raising any question already raised? Need to understand what is the way to go ahead? I can not add comments on my deleted answer so raising question on Meta.

Comment: What issue have you encountered? Has your answer been deleted? Have you received a message from the moderators?

Comment: @yivi: Message from Moderator to delete answer is "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own. See How to reference material written by others and How do I write a good answer?. "

Comment: Answer is now undeleted after the content issues have been rectified.

Comment: *This is still largely plagiarized, so I'm deleting it again. – Brad Larson♦ 17 hours ago*

Comment: @SamuelLiew: Answer is deleted now again? What's new rule in 15 days?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk This is simple: *Do not plagiarize content, ever*. If your answer is just copy paste from another source, then it's not a valid answer. The posted answer should be *your* answer, using *your* words. You can use some external references to support your answer, sure, but your answer should not be made entirely (or mostly) from external content.

Comment: Plagiarism definition "the practice of taking someone else's work or ideas and passing them off as one's own". Where did I say the documentation or engine itself is written by me? I have already given references of pages. Without using technical terms from documentation, how can you explain storage engines features? Do you want to allow this types of questions at all or not? `If your answer is just copy paste from another source`. Can you please compare the source and answer?  `The content is already available, no need to copy it in Stack Overflow.` Are you sure about this?  @Moritz

Comment: @Moritz: My concern are
1. Content is not copied. Compare source and answer. Made bullet points from official doc
2. `Elsewhere`/ `other people's work` is Mysql official doc. If we are allowing theoretical/documentation questions then technical words from doc can come in answer
3. `you are still copying entire parts of other people's work and posting it as your answer`. You need to compare official doc and my answer. If you are saying technical terms taken from doc. Then is it wrong to take these words?
4. `Please respect the way it works on this site.`. I know how site works from 7 years.

Answer (score 15):

The problem isn't that your answer is "theoretical" or that it contains technical terms. The problem is that you plagiarised content, in this case from the official documentation. The way your answer is written, it appears as if it's original content written by you.

I personally don't agree with always having to describe in your own words what the quoted information means, sometimes the quoted information really doesn't need any additional explanation.
But at the very least you must use blockquote formatting and you must attribute the content (link to the source).

Comment: Yes, in particular the *partial* use of quotes is problematic, as it suggests that only the list was taken from the source when in reality the *entire* text was taken, wholesale, from the source. On top of that, there is no original content to go with the copied content, which is what is meant by "use their words and ideas to support your own".

Comment: "I personally don't agree with always having to describe in your own words what the quoted information means, sometimes the quoted information really doesn't need any additional explanation." .Exactly this is my point. What other I could have written to support official doc. Also I have added source references in answer. How better I should have written so user understand different engines and some details about it too. @Stijn

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Do you understand BoltClock's comment? You put a part of the answer in blockquote formatting, while everything should be in blockquote formatting (because you didn't write it yourself).

Comment: @Stijn: I got your point. What if I change the answer like "use their words and ideas to support your own". Can answer be undeleted?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Not sure. Are you able to edit the answer still? If so, you could try editing it and then flagging it for moderator attention.

Comment: @Stijn: I have edited answer. Check if it satisfies the mandates required for writing reference material.

Comment: @BoltClock: Is it satisfying our motto "use their words and ideas to support your own". Thanks for suggesting improvements.